# SharePoint List Create item in Main list & Look up list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, splistitem, ajax

I want to read an excel file & create items in main list and lookup list. The main list is creating an item, but it's not returning the ID synchronously. I tried Success callbacks & deferred, but nothing is working.

**Method 1:**

```
function CreateRoleRights(rowValue,listDtls,success, error)
    {
    var objRightsRoleList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listDtls[0]);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    oRightsRoleListItem = objRightsRoleList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 

    selectedUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("dns\\"+rowValue[0]);   

    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[0], selectedUser);   

    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[1], rowValue[3]);

    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[2], rowValue[4]);

    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[3], rowValue[8]);

    if(manager.length>0)

    {

    selectedUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(manager);  

    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[4], selectedUser); 

    }  

    oRightsRoleListItem.update();

    clientContext.load(oRightsRoleListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
        itemId=oRightsRoleListItem.get_id();
          success(oRightsRoleListItem);
        },
      error);
};
```

**Method 2:**

```
function CreateRoleRightsListItems(rowValue,listDtls){

var dfd = $.Deferred(function() {
var objRightsRoleList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listDtls[0]);
var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
var oRightsRoleListItem = objRightsRoleList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 
selectedUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser("dns\\"+rowValue[0]);   
oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[0], selectedUser);   
oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[1], rowValue[3]);
oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[2], rowValue[4]);
oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[3], rowValue[8]);
if(manager.length>0)
{
    selectedUser = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(manager);  
    oRightsRoleListItem.set_item(columnNamesInternal[   4], selectedUser); 
}  
oRightsRoleListItem.update();
clientContext.load(oRightsRoleListItem);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
                // Successfull
                dfd.resolve(oRightsRoleListItem);      
            },
            function(sender, args) {
                // Failure
                dfd.reject(args.get_message());
            });
    });
    return dfd.promise();
};
```